# Deploy Nodejs+Express+React+Webpack app on heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, webpack

I have made a web app using node js, express, webpack, react and socket io and I would like to deploy it on heroku. When I try it I can access to the website but it shows me an error message:

> Cannot GET /

Here is my configuration:

```
    "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "client": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --devtool inline-source-map --hot",
    "server": "nodemon src/server/index.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install && npm run build"
  }
```

The start script was `node src/server/index.js` before I change it because I run `npm run dev` to start my app locally.

Here is my repository: http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a

Here is the heroku link: https://fast-earth-60949.herokuapp.com

Here are the heroku logs:

> 2018-11-05T21:42:44.984679+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a) Built at: 11/05/2018 9:42:44 PM
>
> 2018-11-05T21:42:44.984681+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)       Asset
>   Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
>
> 2018-11-05T21:42:44.984683+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)   bundle.js   7.42
>   MiB    main  [emitted]  main
>
> 2018-11-05T21:42:44.984685+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a) favicon.ico   40.4
>   KiB          [emitted]
>
> 2018-11-05T21:42:44.984686+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)  index.html  717
>   bytes          [emitted]
>
> 2018-11-05T21:42:44.984688+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a) Entrypoint main =
>   bundle.js
>
> 2018-11-05T21:42:44.984710+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js] 7.68 KiB {main} [built]
>
> 2018-11-05T21:42:44.984712+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/react-dom/index.js] 1.33 KiB {main} [built]
>
> 2018-11-05T21:42:44.984713+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/react/index.js] 190 bytes {main} [built]
>   2018-11-05T21:42:44.984715+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/url/url.js] 22.8 KiB {main} [built]
>
> 2018-11-05T21:42:44.984718+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost:3000]
>   (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 7.78 KiB {main}
>   [built]
>
> 2018-11-05T21:42:44.984720+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js]
>   (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.58 KiB {main} [built]
>
> 2018-11-05T21:42:44.984723+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a) [0] multi
>   (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000
>   (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/client/index.js 52 bytes {main}
>   [built]
>
> 2018-11-05T21:42:44.984724+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/socket.js]
>   (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.05 KiB {main} [built]
>
> 2018-11-05T21:42:44.984726+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js]
>   (webpack)-dev-server/node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {main}
>   [built]
>
> 2018-11-05T21:42:44.984728+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/webpack/hot sync ^./log$] (webpack)/hot sync
>   nonrecursive ^./log$ 170 bytes {main} [built]
>
> 2018-11-05T21:42:44.984730+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js] (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js
>   1.61 KiB {main} [built]
>
> 2018-11-05T21:42:44.984732+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/webpack/hot/emitter.js] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 75
>   bytes {main} [built]
>
> 2018-11-05T21:42:44.984733+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/webpack/hot/log-apply-result.js]
>   (webpack)/hot/log-apply-result.js 1.27 KiB {main} [built]
>
> 2018-11-05T21:42:44.984735+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./src/client/Layout.js] 4.33 KiB {main} [built]
>
> 2018-11-05T21:42:44.984736+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./src/client/index.js] 205 bytes {main} [built]
>
> 2018-11-05T21:42:44.984738+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)     + 349 hidden
>   modules
>
> 2018-11-05T21:42:44.984740+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a) Child
>   html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
>
> 2018-11-05T21:42:44.984742+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)      1 asset
>
> 2018-11-05T21:42:44.984743+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)     Entrypoint
>   undefined = index.html
>
> 2018-11-05T21:42:44.984745+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./public/index.html]
>   828 bytes {0} [built]
>
> 2018-11-05T21:42:44.984746+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js] 527 KiB {0}
>   [built]2018-11-05T21:42:44.984748+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js] (webpack)/buildin/global.js
>   489 bytes {0} [built]
>
> 2018-11-05T21:42:44.984749+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js] (webpack)/buildin/module.js
>   497 bytes {0} [built]
>
> 2018-11-05T21:42:44.984751+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a) ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled
>   successfully.
>
> 2018-11-05T22:16:20.551630+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
>
> 2018-11-05T22:16:20.552092+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up
>   to down
>
> 2018-11-05T22:16:21.411951+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes
>   with SIGTERM
>
> 2018-11-05T22:16:21.808625+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
>   status 143
>
> 2018-11-06T08:35:42.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user
>   kamal.allali@outlook.fr
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:36.888512+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   down to starting
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:36.713630+00:00 app[api]: Deploy d62783d3 by user
>   kamal.allali@outlook.fr
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:36.713630+00:00 app[api]: Release v12 created by user
>   kamal.allali@outlook.fr
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:40.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:42.010068+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
>   command `npm start`
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:45.324322+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:45.324353+00:00 app[web.1]: > projet-web-5a@1.0.0
>   start /app
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:45.324355+00:00 app[web.1]: > npm run dev
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:45.324356+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:45.753063+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:45.753112+00:00 app[web.1]: > projet-web-5a@1.0.0 dev
>   /app
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:45.753114+00:00 app[web.1]: > concurrently "npm run
>   server" "npm run client"
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:45.753116+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:47.147860+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:47.147877+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a) > projet-web-5a@1.0.0
>   client /app
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:47.147879+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a) > webpack-dev-server
>   --mode development --devtool inline-source-map --hot
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:47.147881+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:47.172481+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:47.172485+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] > projet-web-5a@1.0.0
>   server /app
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:47.172487+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] > nodemon
>   src/server/index.js
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:47.172488+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:47.672353+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] [nodemon] 1.18.4
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:47.673281+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] [nodemon] to restart
>   at any time, enter `rs`
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:47.673747+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] [nodemon] watching:
>   /app/src/server/**/*
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:47.674424+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] [nodemon] starting
>   `node src/server/index.js`
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:47.963706+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] Listening on port
>   45437
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:48.299567+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   starting to up
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:48.679674+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a) clean-webpack-plugin:
>   /app/dist has been removed.
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:48.905698+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a) ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is
>   running at http://localhost:3000/
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:48.906031+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a) ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack
>   output is served from /
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:48.956210+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a) ⚠ ｢wds｣: Unable to
>   open browser. If you are running in a headless environment, please do
>   not use the --open flag
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:55.276089+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
>   path="/" host=fast-earth-60949.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=2474b83b-65ce-43b4-a54f-6851d5f55a7c fwd="78.112.168.129"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=404 bytes=360 protocol=https
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:57.303048+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a) ℹ ｢wdm｣: Hash:
>   6de9947fac0c16b70883
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:57.303058+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a) Version: webpack
>   4.19.1
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:57.303061+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a) Time: 8512ms
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:57.303063+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a) Built at: 11/06/2018
>   8:36:57 AM
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:57.303066+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)       Asset
>   Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:57.303069+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)   bundle.js   7.42
>   MiB    main  [emitted]  main
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:57.303071+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a) favicon.ico   40.4
>   KiB          [emitted]
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:57.303073+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)  index.html  717
>   bytes          [emitted]
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:57.303074+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a) Entrypoint main =
>   bundle.js
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:57.303077+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js] 7.68 KiB {main} [built]
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:57.303078+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/react-dom/index.js] 1.33 KiB {main} [built]
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:57.303080+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/react/index.js] 190 bytes {main} [built]
>   2018-11-06T08:36:57.303082+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/url/url.js] 22.8 KiB {main} [built]
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:57.303084+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost:3000]
>   (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 7.78 KiB {main}
>   [built]
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:57.303087+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js]
>   (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.58 KiB {main} [built]
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:57.303090+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a) [0] multi
>   (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000
>   (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/client/index.js 52 bytes {main}
>   [built]
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:57.303091+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/socket.js]
>   (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.05 KiB {main} [built]
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:57.303093+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js]
>   (webpack)-dev-server/node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {main}
>   [built]
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:57.303095+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/webpack/hot sync ^./log$] (webpack)/hot sync
>   nonrecursive ^./log$ 170 bytes {main} [built]
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:57.303099+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js] (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js
>   1.61 KiB {main} [built]
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:57.303100+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/webpack/hot/emitter.js] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 75
>   bytes {main} [built]
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:57.303102+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/webpack/hot/log-apply-result.js]
>   (webpack)/hot/log-apply-result.js 1.27 KiB {main} [built]
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:57.303104+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./src/client/Layout.js] 4.33 KiB {main} [built]
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:57.303106+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./src/client/index.js] 205 bytes {main} [built]
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:57.303108+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)     + 349 hidden
>   modules
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:57.303109+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a) Child
>   html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:57.303111+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)      1 asset
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:57.303113+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)     Entrypoint
>   undefined = index.html
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:57.303115+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./public/index.html]
>   828 bytes {0} [built]
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:57.303116+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js] 527 KiB {0}
>   [built]2018-11-06T08:36:57.303118+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js] (webpack)/buildin/global.js
>   489 bytes {0} [built]
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:57.303119+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a)
>   [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js] (webpack)/buildin/module.js
>   497 bytes {0} [built]
>
> 2018-11-06T08:36:57.303457+00:00 app[web.1]: [1](http://git.kamal-allali.fr/kamal/prog_web_5a) ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled
>   successfully.

Comment: Can you add heroku logs to your question? If possible, a link to your web app would also help.

Comment: So the first thing I notice your file organization. Could you explain how you started this project? Why do you have the Node and React stuff inside of `src`? Did you not start the backend first in the root folder and then add a `client` folder for the `create-react-app` work? Please explain. The `client` folder should have its own `package.json` file.

Comment: I used the following tutorial: https://github.com/vlw0052/Tutorial---ReactJS-and-Socket.io-Chat-App

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your node version to your `package.json`.

#### Example:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.11.0"
  }
```

I answered in the comments but it is not the best way so I'll edit here.

Since you are trying to serve static content try with the static middleware.

Remove

```
app.get('*', (req,res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'../../public/index.html'));
});
```

And add

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'../../public')));
```

Second edit.

You need to build your project and serve the folder, usually is a dist or build folder.

To do this you have a couple of options, one is to build the project before publishing your changes to heroku but it can get a bit tedious.

The other option is to do a postinstall script so after heroku executes npm install the project gets built and the dist or build folder created with the latest changes.

```
"postinstall": "npm run build"
```

If you don't want the script to run everytime you do npm install you can use if-env with an environtment variable in heroku.

```
"postinstall": "if-env NODE_ENV=production && npm run build"
```

Once you know what folder is being created when building change the next line.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'path to the folder with the prod build')));
```

Comment: I added these lines in my package.json, but I still have the same result

Comment: It doesn't show me the error anymore, but I have a blank page. It doesn't shows me my React components

Comment: My bad, I thought you were using public as your build folder. I updated the post to clarify. I'll let you here a link to a repo where I did what I'm explaining in the post. https://github.com/rmartide/vue-playground the server is in src/server.

Comment: `npm run build` creates a dist folder but when I try it on heroku it tells me `Not found`. When I go in heroku console and type `ls` I can see dist folder.

Comment: You could try and build the project and push it to heroku with the dist folder created and see if it works. And then refine it to autobuild after install or something like that. Make sure the path to the folder is correct, maybe that is what is happening. Test it first on the localhost to make sure.

Comment: I tried to push dist folder but I still have the same error. It tells me that the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Did you tried it on your local machine before pushing to see if it works? Also have you tried with the postinstall script?

Comment: It works now, I pushed dist folder and I added a Procfile.

Answer (score 0):

Without the Heroku logs, its kinda of a speculation...BUT

Cannot GET / - means express is not answering to the path..

Heroku is serving NodeJs using express and thats where the bug should be

From checking the code in server/index.js you are using `path` package and forgot to import it :)

```
const path = require('path');
```

Once you fix that you will also need to add a condition to reach `DIST` folder and not public (As you will be serving the DIST folder)

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
    app.get('*', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
}
```

*Also check dist is loading and is not on *.gitignore*

Good luck!